# What is this common path in svg

Tags: svg

I have a bunch of svg icons all with the same second line. What is this second line. Importantly, can i assume it to be same for my own icons.

```
 <path d="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" fill="" />
 <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />

 <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
 <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
```

Also removing that had no effect on my svg icons

Comment: looks like a box round the shape. There's not enough information to say what it's for or why you'd want it.

Comment: i want to remove it ;)

Comment: So remove it then, we're not stopping you.